# Xpath to extract text between specific div tag and next div

Tags: html, r, xpath

I want to extract text in `<p>` between the `div` tag 'Heading1' and the next `div` tag, in the example below. I can't used 'heading2 to isolate the next `div` as this text may change.

```
library(XML)
# create example html
html <- '
<div class="AAA">
<div class="AAA">Heading1</div>
</div>
<p>text1 I want</p>
<p>text2 I want</p>
<p>text3 I want</p>
<div class="AAA">
<div class="AAA">Heading2</div> <!-- Do not always know what this heading is -->
</div>
<p>more text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<div class="AAA">
<div class="AAA">Heading3</div>
</div>'

doc <- htmlParse(html)

xpath <- "//p[preceding::div[@class='AAA' and contains(., 'Heading1')]]"

xpathSApply(doc, xpath, xmlValue)
```

This works up to here, but I'm stuck with limiting the xpath at the next div. I have tried using the following, thinking it would get the next `div`.

```
"//p[preceding::div[@class='AAA' and contains(., 'Heading1')]and following::div[position()=1]]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to test the next div. You should be able to do something like this...

```xml
//p[preceding-sibling::div[1][normalize-space()='Heading1']]
```

or this if the class matters...

```xml
//p[preceding-sibling::div[1][@class='AAA'][normalize-space()='Heading1']]
```

or this if you need to still use `contains()`...

```xml
//p[preceding-sibling::div[1][@class='AAA'][contains(normalize-space(),'Heading1')]]
```

Comment: Id' be grateful if  you could explain the normalize-space part of the xpath - it's not clear to me how this is working from looking at what it does (ie strip white space?)

Comment: @CCID - It returns the string value of the context node with leading/trailing spaces removed and multiple spaces replaced with a single space. ([See here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-normalize-space)) I used it here so the whitespace of the outer div wouldn't be an issue. You wouldn't need it when using the `contains()` for just `Heading1`.

Comment: @CCID - I probably should've also noted that if you add the positional predicate, your initial attempt works fine: `//p[preceding::div[1][@class='AAA' and contains(., 'Heading1')]]`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
//p[preceding-sibling::div[div="Heading1"] and count(preceding-sibling::div[div])=1]
```