# Xpath: How to select following siblings until a similar current node

Tags: html, xpath

```html
<tr><strong>dynamic title</strong></tr>
<tr>1</tr>
<tr>2</tr>
<tr>3</tr>
<tr><strong>static title</strong></tr>
<tr>4</tr>
<tr>5</tr>
<tr><strong>dynamic title</strong></tr>
<tr>6</tr>
<tr>7</tr>
<tr><strong>dynamic title</strong></tr>
<tr>8</tr>
<tr>9</tr>
```

Given the above scenario, I want to select the values 4 and 5 using the static title as a marker.

`//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[strong][contains(.,"static title")]]` or
`//tr[strong[contains(.,"static title")]]/following-sibling::tr`

This will select 6,7,8 and 9 too.
Is there a way to make it select the first preceding-sibling with strong and then check for the contains? Or maybe we can use count() somehow?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65201843/317052) will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert `[1]` after `strong` which means "the first strong preceding sibling must be static":

```
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[strong][1][contains(.,"static title")]]
```

Comment: I think we should not(strong) the in the main tr too.
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[strong][1][contains(.,"static title")]][not(strong)]

Answer (score 0):

This looks little messy, but should work:

```
//tr[contains(strong,"static title")]/following-sibling::tr[strong][1]/preceding-sibling::tr[preceding-sibling::tr[contains(strong,"static title")]]
```